# redirect with hash angular 2

Tags: facebook, angular, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have been developing a facebook login app with angular2.I have an issue with redirect url of facebook token.

My codes simply as follows

**component**

```
export class FbAuthComponent{
    private hrefFb = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/&scope=email&response_type=token"

    onFacebookLoginClick(){
        window.location.href = this.hrefFb; 
    }
}
```

**router**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes ,{ useHash: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

Here I can't remove `useHash: true` inside my root module
and my facebook **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** has been set to **http://localhost:4200/**

the problem is when I click the login button **onFacebookLoginClick** method is fired and then browser navigate to `http://localhost:4200/?#access_token=MY_TOKEN` and just immediately navigate again to `http://localhost:4200/#/access_token` with removing the token.I need to get this access token and I was unable to get it through this way

I can't use FB.login() with the SDK and need to use same window login concept using [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/)

Anybody can explain how to resolve this or a better way to do this?

thanks in advance.